# Compute rand7() using rand5()

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, random

I have a solution for the problem to generate rand7() using only rand5(). 
One of the solution states:
 `5 * rand5() + rand5()` would generate number 0 - 24 in equal probability so we just need to loop until we get a number < 21 ( 3 * 7 ) than % 7 to get the right answer between 0 - 6.

My question is why couldn't we just do `3 * rand5() + rand5()` to generate number < 14 ( 2 * 7 ) instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `X` and `Y` are [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29) and [uniformly distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) on the set `S_5 = {0,1,2,3,4}`, then

1. `5*X + Y` is uniformly distributed on the set `{0,...,24}`, but
2. `3*X + Y` is not uniformly distributed on `{0,...,16}` and neither is its restriction on `{0,...,13}`

It's easy to see that (1) is indeed the case, because `f(x,y) = 5*x + y` is a bijection between `S_5 x S_5` and `S_25`.

If we look at the distribution of `3*X + Y` we get:

```
>>> Counter(3*x + y for x in range(5) for y in range(5))
Counter({3: 2, 4: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 5: 1, 8: 1, 11: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1}
```

The results 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13 are twice as likely as 1, 2, 5, 8 or 11. More proof:

```
>>> def rand7():
...   x = 3*rand5() + rand5()
...   if x < 14: return x % 7
...   return rand7()
... 
>>> Counter(rand7() for _ in xrange(100000))
Counter({6: 18219, 3: 18105, 4: 13734, 5: 13715, 2: 13634, 0: 13560, 1: 9033}
```

6 and 3 have a 4/22 ~ 18.2% chance of occuring, 4, 5, 2 and 0 have an 3/22 ~ 13.6% chance and 1 only has a 2/22 ~ 9.1% chance. That's one rigged dice.

Answer (score 9):

```
3 * rand5() + rand5()
```

is not uniformly distributed. For example, it generates 0 in only one way, but 3 two ways, so 3 is more likely to occur than 0.

It's just like `2 * rand5() * rand5()`, `4 * rand5() + rand5()`, etc.

But `5 * rand5() + rand5()` is uniformly distributed.

It is like generating two random digits of a base-5 number.

```
00 => 0
01 => 1
02 => 2
03 => 3
04 => 4
10 => 5
11 => 6
12 => 7
...
```

There is only and only one way to generate each number from 0 to 24.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a uniform distribution, the contributions of the two random numbers have to be independent. This means the range of the one must not overlap the range of the other, nor must there be any gaps.

In your proposed method there are two ways to get a 3 for example: the first random number returns 1 and the second returns 0, or the first returns 0 and the second returns 3. This makes it twice as likely to occur than a result of 0, which can only occur if both random numbers are 0.

Comment: Well there can be overlaps, but the number of ways to achieve a result must be equal for all results.